Saving Multiple CachedRowset row changes to Database
I am writing a simple program that updates records in a CachedRowset. For some reason it will only save a rowset with only one record. If the rowset contains more than one record when I iterate through the records and change each one in the CachedRowset it won't apply these changes in the database.
I have no problems getting data from the database.  When I say fundamental I mean to have a great number of users on a database the rowset needs to be disconnected else the application will come to a grinding halt.  I do understand that using prepared statements guards against SQL injection but in this application I'm the only one using the software
The code below takes a reference Id from the master table and stores it in a foreign key in a child table.  The reason behind the code is that  I built a comprehensive manufacturing software system and at the time I didn't use and auto increment column for the Id field. Instead I use character values for the Id field. Now I am changing it all to auto increments but to do that I have to update all the foreign keys of the child tables.
private void FillForeignKey(String strDeprecated_Id_Column, String strChild_Table_Name, String strChildForeignKey_Column,
                            Integer intNewMaster_Id, String strOldMaster_Id) throws SQLException {

     try {
        Connection connection = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:5222/jobtrack", "root", "");
        //Select Master table with

        String seqlChild = "SELECT " + strDeprecated_Id_Column + ", " + strChildForeignKey_Column +
                " FROM " + strChild_Table_Name +
                " Where " + strDeprecated_Id_Column +" = " +  "'" + strOldMaster_Id + "'";
        System.out.println(seqlChild);

        Statement stChild = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsChild = stChild.executeQuery(seqlChild);
        RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
        CachedRowSet crsetChild = factory.createCachedRowSet();
        crsetChild.populate(rsChild);
        rsChild.close();
        //connection.close();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        System.out.println("Child Rowset Size " + crsetChild.size());
        System.out.println("New Id " + intNewMaster_Id);
        System.out.println("Old Id " + strOldMaster_Id);

        while (crsetChild.next()) {

            crsetChild.updateInt(strChildForeignKey_Column, intNewMaster_Id);
            crsetChild.moveToCurrentRow();
            System.out.println("Data From child Rowset " + crsetChild.getInt(strChildForeignKey_Column));
            crsetChild.updateRow();
            crsetChild.acceptChanges(connection);
        }

        crsetChild.close();
            //connection.close();

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}


For reasons that escape me, the RowSet feature never got much love or attention from the Java community. (It is quite the sleeper-feature IMHO.) So, you may be better off writing straight SQL in your data migration. By the way, a database change management tool may be helpful, such as Flyway or Liquibase.
